# How to transfer a custom class from 1 file to another

Tags: java

I'm writing a program in Java that needs to call a custom class from a different file to the main one on a method that makes and returns an array with said class.

I tried just recreating the same class on the new file and extend it to the main one but still can't find the symbol for said class.

Example: File A creates CustomClass[] which CustomClass is created in File B.

First post here and sorry for bad English.

Comment: Could you add a minimised code sample, it is not clear what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You have to import that class. If they are in the same package (folder) you hate to write before the

```
public class a
```

you write

```
import b;
```

then you can use that class like the other that you import.